# Can SOLR custom analyzer access another field's value?

Tags: solr

I am trying to write a custom i18n analyzer , whose execution is determined by the value of another field within the document.

For example if the locale field in the document has 'de' as the value, then the i18nCustomAnalyzer would use the German set of tokenizers/filters to process the value of a field. Similarly if the locale=jp, then the i18nCustomAnalyzer must use the japanese set of tokenizers/filters to analyze the content of a field.

My question is : how can a custom analyzer access the value of another field (in this case locale field) within a document, while analyzing the value of a specific field?

Edit: There is a solution where we can prepend the locale value to the field's value viz. de|fieldvalue
Then the i18n custom analyzer can extract the locale while analyzing the field value. This seems a dirty solution to me. Hence finding out if any solr/lucene experts have any better solution. I am sure i am not asking something which has not been thought or solved before.